# Decorator pattern - how to decorate two types at once

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I work in Java

I created a nice structure of decorators for graph edges. I have base edge with two vertices, then I have a weighted decorator that adds a weight to an edge and then I have a oriented decorator that adds orientation to an edge. Decorators are implemented using interfaces and delegate methods (not by inheritance).

Now I would like to add another decorator - a flow decorator, corresponding to a flow edge. Flow edges have both direction and weight (the capacity), plus the flow. How do I implement something like this in Java? I would need something like

```
public class FlowEdge implements IEdge, IWeightedEdge, IOrientedEdge, IFlowEdge
{
    private IEdge, IWeightedEdge, IOrientedEdge decorated;
    private int flow;

    //constructors, delegate methods...
```

but that's obviously not possible.

Maybe the decorator is not the best pattern to use. I would like to achieve the separation of concerns (so I could have any combination of normal, weighted, oriented edges), but also need functionality of possibly multiple decorators in one class. Is this somehow possible? Or am I over-engineering this?

Comment: Why is this "obviously not possible"? You can only `extend` one class, but you can `implement` any number of interfaces.

Comment: I meant the line 
private IEdge, IWeightedEdge, IOrientedEdge decorated;
in order to preserve all types I will need to implement delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I let go of this whole decorator idea and implemented the edges just like normal inheritace.

Edge --> WeightedEdge --> OrientedEdge --> FlowEdge

It is maybe not as elegant as using decorations and I cannot now have unweighted oriented edge, but it is straightforward and easy.

Answer (score 1):

> Decorators are implemented using interfaces and delegate methods (not
>   by inheritance).

I think this could be a reason why you're running into a wall. Decorator pattern yields itself nicely in Java by using inheritance and polymorphism. This is a good example of "Programming 'in' a language vs programming 'into' a language".

Comment: How do I then decorate one class with two decorators? I cannot inherit from two classes in Java.

Comment: That's not exactly how decorators work in Java. You don't inherit as much as you... decorate at runtime. For example: new BufferedReader(new FileReader("readme.txt")).

Answer (score 1):

Your design sounds flawed. Decorators typically "wrap" the class they want to decorate, which is passed into their constructor. Your code should make something like this possible:

```
Graph myGraph = new BaseGraph();
Graph decoratedGraph = new FlowedGraph(new WeightedGraph(new OrientedGraph(myGraph)));
```

Comment: Thank you... yes that's decorator as I was taught it. But FlowedGraph must have both direction and weight and I cannot guarantee in this case that the "decoree" will be both. I can make it only weighted or oriented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a mistake to declare the type of decoration that a decorator implements. It also seems wrong for a decorator to know exactly what it is decorating. You can implement a "compound decorator" that relies on other decorator classes to add specific behavior in addition to new behavior that itself provides. Perhaps something like this:

```
public class FlowEdge implements IEdge // or IFlowEdge
{
    private IEdge decorated;
    private int flow;

    public FlowEdge(IEdge decorated) {
        this.decorated = new WeightedEdge(new OrientedEdge(decorated));
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: An interesting idea, but then I must have arbitrary values for weight and direction, as they cannot be passed in the constructor (other that checking for type and then casting to appropriate type).

Comment: @JakubZaverka - Why can't the relevant properties be passed in the constructor? From what you describe, `FlowEdge` properties include all the properties of `WeightedEdge` and `OrientedEdge`. These can then be passed on to the relevant constructors inside the `FlowEdge` constructor. (Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something; I don't see why you'd need to do any type checking and casting here.)

Comment: `FlowEdge(WeightedEdge wedge, OrientedEdge oedge)` I was down this road a while, but it didn't seem clean, you could pass two different instances. I would have to check `if(wedge != oedge)` and then throw some kind of exception. That is already at runtime, I would like to have it checked at compile time.